# slick carousel with different "slidesToShow" at different positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I want a [slick carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), where, in some positions, it shows 3 slides, and in others, it shows 1 slide. Here is something I tried:

```js
$(".carousel").slick({
  // IMPORTANT
  variableWidth: true,
  // not so important
  dots: true,
  appendArrows: $(".carousel-arrows"),
  nextArrow: "<button>Next</button>",
  prevArrow: "<button>Previous</button>"
});

$(".wanted-behavior").click(function() {
  $(".carousel").slick("slickGoTo", 0, true);
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickPrev");}, 500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 2000)
});
$(".unwanted-behavior").click(function() {
  $(".carousel").slick("slickGoTo", 1, true);
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 1500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 2500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickPrev");}, 4000)
});
```

```css
/* IMPORTANT */
.carousel-img {
  width: 33vw!important;
}
.carousel-img-big {
  width: 100vw!important;
}

/* not so important */
.carousel-img img,
.carousel-img-big img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-HGOnQO9+SP1V92SrtZfjqxxtLmVzqZpjFFekvzZVWoiASSQgSr4cw9Kqd2+l8Llp4Gm0G8GIFJ4ddwZilcdb8A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="carousel-arrows"></div>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/201"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/202"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/203"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img-big"><img src="https://picsum.photos/204"></div>
</div>

<button class="wanted-behavior" type="button">Wanted Behaviour</button>
<button class="unwanted-behavior" type="button">Unwanted Behaviour</button>
```

This simply uses the `variableWidth` option of slick carousels, where slides are set to `33vw`, and one is set to `100vw`.
The problem with it is that some of the carousel's positions only shows a fraction of the big (`100vw`) slide, which I don't want. There should be either 3 slides on the screen or one big one. I have added buttons to display the wanted and unwanted behavior of it.
So generally, my question is:

> "*How can I have a [slick carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), with different positions showing a differing number of slides?*"

Perhaps there's something entirely different from what I've tried above that works, it's just what I tried.
Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of this question... I have actually found an answer, I just feel it's overly convoluted for the simple thing I'm trying to do and I believe there is a better way. But since there hasn't been much activity on this post, I'll give my answer anyways (although I won't accept it).

Continuing what I tried in the question, I have a slick carousel with the `variableWidth` option, and slides taking up `33vw`, except for one, which takes up `100vw`.

```js
$(".carousel").slick({
  // IMPORTANT
  variableWidth: true,
  // not so important
  dots: true,
  appendArrows: $(".carousel-arrows"),
  nextArrow: "<button>Next</button>",
  prevArrow: "<button>Previous</button>"
});

$(".wanted-behavior").click(function() {
  $(".carousel").slick("slickGoTo", 0, true);
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickPrev");}, 500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 2000)
});
$(".unwanted-behavior").click(function() {
  $(".carousel").slick("slickGoTo", 1, true);
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 1500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickNext");}, 2500)
  setTimeout(function() {$(".carousel").slick("slickPrev");}, 4000)
});
```

```css
/* IMPORTANT */
.carousel-img {
  width: 33vw!important;
}
.carousel-img-big {
  width: 100vw!important;
}

/* not so important */
.carousel-img img,
.carousel-img-big img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-HGOnQO9+SP1V92SrtZfjqxxtLmVzqZpjFFekvzZVWoiASSQgSr4cw9Kqd2+l8Llp4Gm0G8GIFJ4ddwZilcdb8A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="carousel-arrows"></div>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/201"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/202"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/203"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img-big"><img src="https://picsum.photos/204"></div>
</div>

<button class="wanted-behavior" type="button">Wanted Behaviour</button>
<button class="unwanted-behavior" type="button">Unwanted Behaviour</button>
```

What I then add is a check, every time before the slide changes, that asks if the slide it want's to go to is a "bad position", if so, it skips the "bad position/s" to the next "good position". Finally, if the carousel has `dots` enabled, we need to remove the dots corresponding to "bad positions", so we do that too. Resulting in this:

```js
$(".carousel").slick({
  // IMPORTANT
  variableWidth: true,
  // not so important
  dots: true,
  appendArrows: $(".carousel-arrows"),
  nextArrow: "<button>Next</button>",
  prevArrow: "<button>Previous</button>"
});

// IMPORTANT

$($(".carousel .slick-dots").children().get().slice(2, 4)).css("display", "none");

$(".carousel").on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if ((nextSlide==2 || nextSlide==3) && (currentSlide!=4)) {
    $(".carousel").slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", false)
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".carousel").slick("slickGoTo", 4, false);
      $(".carousel").slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", true);
    }, 1);
  } else if ((nextSlide==2 || nextSlide==3) && (currentSlide==4)) {
    $(".carousel").slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", false)
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".carousel").slick("slickGoTo", 1, false);
      $(".carousel").slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", true);
    }, 1);
  };
});
```

```css
/* IMPORTANT */
.carousel-img {
  width: 33vw!important;
}
.carousel-img-big {
  width: 100vw!important;
}

/* not so important */
.carousel-img img,
.carousel-img-big img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-HGOnQO9+SP1V92SrtZfjqxxtLmVzqZpjFFekvzZVWoiASSQgSr4cw9Kqd2+l8Llp4Gm0G8GIFJ4ddwZilcdb8A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="carousel-arrows"></div>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/201"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/202"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/203"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img-big"><img src="https://picsum.photos/204"></div>
</div>
```